# Windows 7 disable media sharing (DLNA) for individual accounts

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, windows-media-player

I have a Win 7 machine with 3 user accounts on it. I stream media from this machine to my LG Smart TV using standard HomeGroup sharing.

However, the TV picks up 3 different input sources corresponding to the shared media libraries for the 3 accounts on my PC. I only want to share the library from one of my PC accounts, but I can't find a way to disable media sharing for individual accounts - turning sharing on and off seems to be an all-or-nothing solution.

Comment: Ever found a solution to this? I'm also looking for registry keys.